# Find regular expression between html tags

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I'm, trying to find the regex for this pattern. I have tried a few things but none of them of work.

I tried this 
    `</a>(.*?)<a name`

```
<a name="13" class="anchor"></a>
      Some Content here
<a name="14" class="anchor"></a>
```

So my expected result should be **Some Content here**

Comment: What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect? What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job:

Find: `</a>\s*\K[\s\S]*?(?=<a name)`

**Explanation:**

```
</a>\s*         # </a> followed by 0 or more spaces
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
[\s\S]*?        # 0 or more any character, including linebreaks
(?=<a name)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have "<a name" after
```